# create a dynamic navigational bar using css

Tags: html, css

I am new in html & css. I am unable to adjust this navigational bar dynamically. My problem is that when I resize window it get disturbed layout and in smaller device it also scattered. I want that when I use smaller device like mobile or when I resize window it shape and layout not change

```
<style>
.page-numbers {
width:99%;
height:34px; 
margin:20px 0 auto;
border:1px solid #ddd;
border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.page-numbers ul li{display:inline;}
.page-numbers a, 
.page-numbers .current{
 float:left;padding:0 14px;
 line-height:34px;
 border-right:1px solid;
 border-right-color:#ddd;
 border-right-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 *border-right-color:#ddd;
 text-decoration:none;
 width:auto;
 }

.page-numbers a:hover,

.page-numbers .active a{background-color:#efefef;}

.page-numbers .current{
 background-color:none;
 color:#bfbfbf;
 }
.page-numbers .next a{border:0;}

</style>


<div class="page-numbers">
<span class="current" style="width:auto">← Previous</span>
<span class="current">1</span>
<a href="http://www.superpathshala.com/2018/05/the-hindu-vocabulary-with- 
mnemonics-english-to-hindi-A2.html" class="page">2</a>
<a href="http://www.superpathshala.com/2018/05/the-hindu-vocabulary-with- 
mnemonics-english-to-hindi-A3.html" class="page">3</a>
<a href="http://www.superpathshala.com/2018/05/the-hindu-vocabulary-with- 
mnemonics-english-to-hindi-A4.html" class="page">4</a>
<a href="http://www.superpathshala.com/2018/05/the-hindu-vocabulary-with- 
mnemonics-english-to-hindi-A5.html" class="page">5</a>
<a href="http://www.superpathshala.com/2018/05/the-hindu-vocabulary-with- 
mnemonics-english-to-hindi-A6.html" class="page">6</a>
<a href="http://www.superpathshala.com/2018/05/the-hindu-vocabulary-with- 
mnemonics-english-to-hindi-A7.html" class="page">7</a>
<a href="http://www.superpathshala.com/2018/05/the-hindu-vocabulary-with- 
mnemonics-english-to-hindi-A8.html" class="page">8</a>
<a href="http://www.superpathshala.com/2018/05/the-hindu-vocabulary-with- 
mnemonics-english-to-hindi-A9.html" class="page">9</a>
<a href="http://www.superpathshala.com/2018/05/the-hindu-vocabulary-with- 
mnemonics-english-to-hindi-A10.html" class="page">10</a>
<a href="http://www.superpathshala.com/2018/05/the-hindu-vocabulary-with- 
mnemonics-english-to-hindi-A2.html" class="nextpostslink" style="border- 
right:none; width:60px">Next →</a>
</div>
```

Comment: try using media queries. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: You have 2 solutions. use media quires .. or any js plugin like mean menu https://www.meanthemes.com/plugins/meanmenu/

Answer (score 0):

Use @media query for creating responsive website
https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is simple and in three ways
1. Using media queries
     This is cdd media queries . Its too simple and handy and always better to learn this
2. Learn any css framework like `Bootstrap`, 
 Using bootstrap is efficieng as it is the market leader in this field but it can take some time to learn 
My suggestion use `skeleton.css` its a boilerplate and for me its the **best**! 
 link :  www.getskeleton.com
3 . Do it with javascript/jquery 
 But this will be the worst choice but it will improve your javascript skills as in todays world JAVASCRIPT IS EVERYWHERE

Answer (score 0):

You could use media-queries to achieve that. A quick example with media-queries and a bit of JS. The working fiddle is [there](https://jsfiddle.net/1gfgybv0/).

**HTML :**

```
<div class="triggers">
  <div class="trigger"></div>
  <div class="trigger"></div>
</div>
<nav>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
</nav>
<h1>
Resize under 720px
</h1>
```

**CSS :**

```
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.triggers {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px; right: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 99;
}

.trigger {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.trigger:nth-child(1).is-active {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.trigger:nth-child(2).is-active {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none; 
  margin: 10px;
}

@media (max-width:720px) {
  .triggers {
    display: flex;
  }

  nav {
    top: -50px;
  }

  nav.is-active {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

**JS (jQuery) :**

```
$(function(){
  $('.triggers').click(function(){
    $('.trigger, nav').toggleClass('is-active');
  });
});
```

Comment: I want use only css is it possible?

Comment: @user3528933 not with this one, you could use some checkbox hack or something to achieve that without JS. You got an example there : https://codepen.io/erikterwan/pen/EVzeRP